# AddForce in Rigidbody2D not working at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been following guides, I have been trudging through dozens of forums, and subsequently, I have been ripping what's left of my hair out!

As you can see in the code, I am trying to use velocity for the movement, and AddForce for the jumping motion. If I use velocity, it jumps super fast and at the maximum, I just don't want this to happen. I want a smooth jump, more realistic, so I saw it said to use AddForce instead. Except.... It doesn't even work at all, he just doesn't jump now... nothing.

I worked with velocity. The code was 
rb.velocity = jumping * jumpForce;

Like I said, this worked, but it was jumping ridiculously fast and didn't look at all correct.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 3.0f;
    public float jumpForce = 4.0f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector2 movement;
    public bool isJumping;
    public Animator animate;
    public Vector2 jumping = new Vector2(0,1);


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //animate = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //animate.SetFloat("Horizontal", Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));

        movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));


    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        moveCharacter(movement);
        jumpCharacter();


    }

    void moveCharacter(Vector2 direction)
    {
        rb.velocity = direction * speed;

    }

    void jumpCharacter()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !isJumping)
        {
            isJumping = true;

            rb.AddForce(jumping * jumpForce);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isJumping = false;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try like this `rigidbody.AddForce(velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.
Where would I put the user defined variable of jumpForce into this?

Comment: Instead of writing `rb.AddForce(jumping * jumpForce);` you will write `rb.AddForce(jumping * jumpForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);`

Comment: That didn't work, but I've spoken to someone on Reddit and they mentioned something about the Update() and FixedUpdate(), whic I am not even too sure about.

Comment: If even other suggestions didn't work, then that only means that problem is outside of this code, maybe your GameObject don't have rigidbody or it's parameters not letting it to move with physics. So try tweaking them, create new gameobject with rigidbody and assign this script and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I've met same situation like you, and I find that using

- `Rigidbody2D.velocity =+ Vector2.up * force;` in `FixedUpdate()`
- instead of `Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * force);` could work.

But I'm also wondering why `AddForce` can not work properly.